Browser stack making calls before reload session complete
Context:
I am using WebdriverIO with Appium 2 and Cucumber. In my beforeScenario hook, I have added a step to reload the session before every scenario since my scenarios cover end-to-end testing. I want to uninstall and install the app after every scenario. Since I cannot achieve this via ADB commands on BrowserStack, I decided to use reloadSession().
Problem:
Before the reloadSession() can fully start a new session, BrowserStack begins making API calls using the previous session ID, which was deleted during the reloadSession call. Essentially, BrowserStack starts sending API calls (404 errors) for the deleted session before the new session is fully created.
Failed API calls:
script: 'browserstack_executor: {"action":"annotate","arguments":{"data":"Scenario: Second Scenario Name","level":"info"}}', args: []
Error log:
[0-0] 2024-10-14T12:41:04.870Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to WebDriver Error: Session not started or terminated [0-0] 2024-10-14T12:41:04.885Z ERROR @wdio/utils:shim: WebDriver Error: Session not started or terminated
The issue is that BrowserStack sends calls for annotating data for the next scenario (which should only happen after a new session is created). Despite using await for reloadSession(), the BrowserStack API calls continue to happen prematurely, before the session is ready.
In my beforeScenario hook:
beforeScenario: async function (world, result, context, scenario) { await browser.reloadSession(); 
// API calls are failing here between these 
console.log("Session reloaded successfully"); 
}
Goal:
I want BrowserStack to wait until my reloadSession() completes—i.e., deletes the old session and fully starts a new one—before making any API calls related to the new session.
